# How to express parameter constraints for $(x-a)\left(x-\frac{1}{a}\right)<0$ if $-1<a<1$ and $a\neq 0$

Tags: inequality

How would one express the constraints on the parameter $x$ to satisfy:
\begin{equation}
\left(x-a\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{a}\right)<0 \quad \mbox{given} \quad -1<a<1\quad \mbox{and} \quad -1<x<1 \quad \mbox{with} \quad x\neq0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad a\neq 0
\end{equation}
It ic clear that the conditions arise from the first bracket, as the second bracket requires $x$ to be outside of the prescribed range.

I thought $x>a$ if $a>0$ and $x<a$ if $a<0$ but is there a more elegant and precise way to say this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the solution to $(x-b)(x-c)<0$ is $\min(b,c) < x < \max(b,c)$ as long as $b \ne c$.

Now $a-\frac{1}{a}=\frac{a^2-1}{a}$ with the numerator always negative, so together with the other constraint $-1<x<1, x\ne 0$ we have:

$a>0 \implies a<\frac 1a \implies a<x<\frac 1a \implies x \in (a,1)$;

$a<0 \implies a>\frac 1a \implies \frac 1a<x<a \implies x \in (-1,a)$;